# switch_root: failed to execute /sbin/init: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: arch-linux, startup, init, shared-library, system-recovery

So, recently I was doing the Linux from scratch project and I had multiple terminals open, so I was continuing to make it, and by accident I typed the line in another terminal tab (root), and it messes up symlinks completely!, I can't run any commands on bash.

```
    case $(uname -m) in
 i?86) ln -sfv ld-linux.so.2 $LFS/lib/ld-lsb.so.3
 ;;
 x86_64) ln -sfv ../lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 $LFS/lib64
 ln -sfv ../lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 $LFS/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
 ;;
esac
```

I'm on arch linux, when I restarted the computer, also the kernel panic happened and it says: "switch_root: failed to execute /sbin/init: Too many levels of symbolic links."

Any solutions? I hope if someone helps.

Comment: You will need to get to a root shell to recover, if it's even possible... maybe try booting your kernel with `init=/bin/sh`.

Comment: @rfmodulator that won't do anything if the system is using an initrd image (the switch_root call suggests that it does), and `/bin/sh` is itself dynamically linked and it will immediately fail with the same error, causing a panic. I suggest the OP to boot from a usb stick, mount the root filesystem and fix from there the `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` symlink.

Comment: @UncleBilly Thanks for the clarification ...but the fact remains that OP needs a root shell to recover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What to recover

The `LFS` variable was presumably unset when you ran this command. So it modified `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and `/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3`.

You've corrupted the [dynamic loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading). As a consequence, you can't run any dynamically linked program. Pretty much every program is dynamically linked, including `bash`, `init`, `ln`, etc.

`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is the important one. It's the dynamic loader used by 64-bit Arch programs. The symbolic link is provided by the [glibc package](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/glibc/). From a working Linux system, run

```
ln -snf ld-2.33.so /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

**Note: the number 2.33 will change over time!** Check what file `/lib/ld-*.so` exists on your system.

`/lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3` is for compatibility with programs not built for Arch. It's provided by the [`ld-lsb` package](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/ld-lsb/). If this package is installed, restore the link:

```
ln -snf ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3
```

If `ld-lsb` is not installed, remove `/lib/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3`.

#### Self-contained recovery with advance planning

When dynamic libraries are corrupted, you can still run statically linked executables. If you're running any kind of unstable or rolling-release system, I recommend having a basic set of statically linked utilities. (Not just a shell: a statically linked bash is of no help to create symbolic links, for instance.) Arch Linux doesn't appear to have one. You can copy the executable from Debian's [busybox-static](https://packages.debian.org/busybox-static) or [zsh-static](https://packages.debian.org/zsh-static): both include a shell as well as built-in core utilities such as `cp`, `ln`, etc.

With such advance planning, provided you still have a running root shell, you can run `busybox-static` and

```
ln -snf ld-2.33.so /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Or run `zsh-static` and

```
zmodload zsh/files
ln -snf ld-2.33.so /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

If you've rebooted and are stuck because `/sbin/init` won't start, boot into the static shell: follow the steps in [Crash during startup on a recent corporate computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436429/crash-during-startup-on-a-recent-corporate-computer) under “Useful debugging techniques:”, starting with “press and hold Shift”. On the `linux` command line, add `init=/bin/busybox-static` (or whatever the correct path is).

#### Repairing from a recovery system

Without advance planning, you'll need to run a working Linux system to repair yours. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/General_troubleshooting#Fixing_a_broken_system) suggests booting a monthly Arch image. You can also use [SysRescueCD](https://www.system-rescue.org/). Either way, use your written notes, `lsblk`, `fdisk -l`, `lvs`, or whatever helps you figure out what your root partition is, and mount it with `mount /dev/… /mnt`. Then repair the symbolic link:

```
ln -snf ld-2.33.so /mnt/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll give it a go, oh man I forgot to export the LFS path, the system was restarted! Such a dumb mistake tbh. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Thank you!! It worked!